# Azure Search load only facets list

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Currently, I've started to explore Azure Cognitive Search and I'm playing with a sample app.

What I'm trying to find is how to load the list of all facets, but I can't find a way.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question description, I understand you want to load only the facets list in Azure Cognitive Search. You may try to load those by Facets property of the `SearchOptions` class.

Take a look at these doc for more info:

[Tutorial: Add faceted navigation using the .NET SDK](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/search/tutorial-csharp-facets.md#set-up-the-search-filter)

[Add faceted navigation to a search app](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/search/search-faceted-navigation.md)

You can add facets to the list by using the Add method.
Take a look at this sample, where we add the Category and Tags facets as follows:

```html
var options = new SearchOptions
{
    Filter = "",
    SearchMode = SearchMode.All,
    IncludeTotalCount = true,
};

options.Facets.Add("Category,count:20");
options.Facets.Add("Tags,count:20");
```